# Can I make a UIView/UIScrollView adapt the size automatically under autolayout like a UILabel?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm building a tableViewCell to display the topics in a BBS,the layout just like the pic,I use a UIView(the gray one) to display the images(insert imageView in it), implement the delegate as

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    ...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    [self configureCell:cell index:indexPath];

    return [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1.0f;
}
```

I change the height constraint of the view according to count of images,but I get some constraint conflicts from the logs when I'm reusing the cell:

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   MASLayoutConstraint:0x1742b3920 UIView:0x14cdbc1f0.height == 783.333

sometimes it even compress the summary label and makes it display abnormally.

The problems is:Can I make a scrollView/UIView resize by the content like UILabel or non-scrollEnable UITextView,or any other better way?

[image]